# How to append text in html using php

Tags: php

I am trying to use php DOM object to achieve this but as i am learning i can not figure out the error

```
 <?php
    //connect  to the database 
  $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "movie");

   //check connection
if(!$connect)
{
    die("Connection Failed : " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "SELECT seatnum FROM seats WHERE moviename = \"spiderman\" ";
     $result=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
     /*if(false === $result)
     {
         echo "error";
     }*/
     $doc = new DOMDocument;
     $parent = $doc->getElementById('details_data');
     if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
     {
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
         {
             $msg = $doc->createTextNode($row["seatnum"]);
             $parent->appendChild($msg);
         }
     }
     ?>
```

O/P for above code :

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function appendChild() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\movie\seat_map\seat.php:90 Stack trace: #0 {main}

Answer (score 0):

First Problem :

Your DOMDocument is empty, so getElementById will return NULL.

If you want to load an existing HTML file, try using  the "loadHtmlFile" method : http://php.net/manual/fr/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php

Comment: file itself is php and not html what should i do ?

Comment: Then, you can import your php file, put the resulting HTML in a var (with the PHP buffer - ob_start and ob_end_clean) and use the loadHtml method